# For what values of $p$ the function $f(z) = \frac{\text{sin}\ z}{z^p}$ is analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis

For what values of $p$ the function $f(z) = \frac{\text{sin}\ z}{z^p}$ is analytic?

How one should proceed? I know that $\text{sin}\ z$ is analytic everywhere. Please help.

Comment: Look at the power series of $\sin(z)$.

Comment: @lhf I think $p$ belongs to set of odd integers. Am I correct?

Comment: Does $p=3$ work?

Comment: A very pedantic answer would be that it always is, since $\frac{1}{z^p}$ is analytic on its domain, which is $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0 \}$.

Comment: If $p$ is not integral, one needs to do a branch cut from zero to infinity to get an analytic or even continuous function